# Install library module jar to local maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am migrating from Eclipse & maven to Android Studio & Gradle build.

My project structure now in Android Studio looks like this:

```
MyApp
 ->LibModule
   -src
   -...
   -lib_repo/
   -build.gradle
 ->AnotherModule
   ...
```

`LibModule` is my library module, I want to install the build jar of `LibModule` to my local maven repository. What I tried in **build.gradle** (under LibModule/ )is:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
...
group = 'com.my.lib'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
    description "Installs the artifacts to the local Maven repository."
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")
            pom.version = '1.1.0'
            pom.artifactId = 'MyLib'
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also tried:

```
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.version = '1.1.0'
        pom.artifactId = 'MyLib'
    }
}
```

I got error "**unsupported Gradle DSL method found 'install()'!** ".

When I build it in Android Studio IDE, in gradle console,  I didn't see anything happen to upload the archive to my local maven repository. I also checked the content of **build/** directory, there is no **poms/** folder at all. It seems it is not triggered, I followed the [gradle document here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:installing_to_the_local_repository). Why? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For installing to the local Maven repository (which is mainly useful when exchanging artifacts with local Maven builds), use the `install` task rather than `uploadArchives`. For details, check the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work either. I got error message "unsupported Gradle DSL method found : 'install()'! ", I updated my question above.